# Dois "em": ... você poderá alterar novamente em em [X] horas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Há mais um "em" nessa mensagem:

[image: "em em"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foi resolvido no Transifex.

Vai pro ar em em alguns minutos